# Unable to register with subscription-manager - 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: rhel, rhel7

In rhel 7 server I am trying to install packages with yum. After getting error that I need to register my rhel7 with `subscription-manager` I got this error:

command:

```
subscription-manager register
```

output:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

after some checks I saw that I need to unregister (the register command dident work but still) and clean the data, but still same error.

The user and password are correct in the red hat website

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
subscription-manager register --auto-attach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands :

```
# subscription-manager clean
```

Remove the empty if it exists /var/lib/rhsm/cache/installed_products.json file.

```
# rm -f /var/lib/rhsm/cache/installed_products.json
```